# problem in changing my primary key column seeding

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, identity

i need a script to change my identity column seeding just from 3000 to 5000

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just curious

Answer (score 8):

**SQLServer**

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName', RESEED, 5000)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Comment: First time I've seen an exact tie!